# convolution of g and g = g

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

Can someone help me with an example?

I would like to find, for g $\in$ $L^2(R)$, the convolution g $\ast$ g = g.

I know that the zero function works. I am looking for a nonzero example.

Thank you!

Comment: In Fourier variable it gives $\hat{g}^2 = \hat{g}$ so that $\hat{g}$ takes only the values $0$ or $1$. You can take for $g$ the inverse Fourier transform of an indicator function, for example the inverse Fourier transform of $\chi_{[0,1]}$.

Comment: I don't know what $L^2(R)$ means. But $sinc(x)$ is an example of a function that after convolution by itself produces the same function. Gribouillis mentioned about $\hat{g}$ taking values of $0$ or $1$. In the case of $sinc$ function, its FT is a rect pulse which is made of 0 and 1.